# Ubuntu reboots before installation

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 Beta 2 with no problem but the stable Ubuntu 18.04 LTS reboots after choosing either try Ubuntu or install Ubuntu. It happens when I try installing Ubuntu in non-UEFI mode. I am using an [ASUS](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/VivoBook-Pro-N552VW/) laptop with a Lexar USB 3 flash drive.

Edit: From boot options menu I pressed Esc button and after accepting the exiting dialog

> You are leaving the graphical boot menu and starting the text mode
>   interface. [OK] [Cancel]

The following message was printed on screen

> [0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata; please
>   update microcode to version: 0xb2 (or later)

and then Ubuntu booted almost without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attempted re-downloading the .iso file from Ubuntu's website? That's what I had to do to fix certain issues.

What I would do is redownload the file and transfer it to a DVD or flash drive. MAKE SURE THAT WINDOWS (or whatever OS you're using) VERIFIES THE TRANSFER. OTHERWISE, IT MAY NOT WORK. Then, you should be good to go.

Comment: I checked the sha256 sum after downloading the iso file and it isn't a dual boot. The only OS is Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dante, just try again. I'm pretty sure that there is a problem with your computer or .iso file. And after checking your computer's specs, I'm certain that it's the .iso file. I'm not trying to sound rude, but just check again.